# Delete an admin file from standard account

Tags: batch-file, command, powershell-cmdlet, psexec

So the case is.

I'm logged in into a standard account I do have the admin username and password. I want to delete a file from that standard account by using the admin name and password using cmd or powershell

I tried with runas that's not working saying that not able to find the specific file

I tried below commands

Runas /profile /user:username "delete name.txt"

Output error : not able to find the file

Comment: How about trying it with the path to the file, instead of just it's name.

Comment: In that case I'm getting access denied error... because I'm a standard user not admin

Comment: Unless you're using a third party script or other executable file with a basename of `delete`, you will need to run `cmd.exe`, to use its internal `delete` command.

Comment: Yes but the cmd.exe saying access denied because I'm an standard user